# How can I fix rEFInd after I removed cryptsetup-initramfs?

Tags: boot, bootloader, refind

I saw an error in my update output that suggested I remove the package cryptsetup-initramfs. I did so, and the next time I rebooted my rEFInd boot screen just stuck on a white, blank screen.

I got back into Ubuntu via my laptop EFI menu and reinstalled the package, but that did not fix the problem. At this stage, I'm only supposing this is what broke rEFInd, as nothing else changed except some recent updates installed (which is where I saw the error I alluded to).

Other things I've tried: Totally removing the rEFInd package and removing /boot/efi/EFI/refind directory and reinstalling it, so now instead of a blank white screen I get the rEFInd logo at the top, but still no OS options (it was hidden in my original refind.conf). I re-ran refind-install and refind-mkdefault, neither of which threw up any problems, and confirmed the refind is the first boot entry in efibootmgr.

What could the problem be and how do I fix it?

Ubuntu 18.10, up to date.

rEFInd 0.11.4 from PPA.

Further info: I enabled textonly mode, and it’s stuck on the message “rEFInd - Inititializing...”.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this fixed it, but I removed the file /boot/efi/EFI/refind/drivers/ext4_x64.efi and now it works.